# Show that $\omega\wedge f(v_1,\ldots,v_m)=f(v)\operatorname{vol} (v_1,\ldots,v_m)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, tensors

> Show for every $\omega\in \wedge^{m-1}(\mathbb R^m)$ exist one only vector $v$ such that $$\omega\wedge f(v_1,\ldots,v_m)=f(v)\operatorname{vol}(v_1,\ldots,v_m)$$
> for all $f\in\wedge^1(\Bbb R^m)$ and for all $v_1,\ldots,v_m$ in $ \Bbb R^m$. Show that exist one isomorphism between $\wedge^{m-1}(\Bbb R^m)$ and $\Bbb R^m$.

My attempt is to try to compute the leftside, I mean

$$\omega\wedge f = \frac{(m-1+1)! }{(m-1)!1!}\operatorname{Alt}(\omega \otimes f)=m\operatorname{Alt}(\omega \otimes f),$$
the other side
$$\operatorname{Alt}(\omega \otimes f)=\frac1{m!} \sum_{\sigma\in S_m} (\operatorname{sign}\sigma ) \omega\otimes f.$$ Then

$$\begin{aligned}\omega\wedge f(v_1\ldots,v_n)&= \frac{m}{m!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_m} (\operatorname{sign }\sigma )\omega(v_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(m-1)}).f(v_{\sigma(m)})\\&=\frac1{(m-1)!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_m}(\operatorname{sign} \sigma)\omega(v_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(m-1)}).f(v_{\sigma(m)}).\end{aligned}$$

How continued this? And $\frac1{(m-1)!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_m}(\operatorname{sign} \sigma)\omega(v_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(m-1)})$ is the volumen element on dimension $\Bbb R^{m-1}$?

Please can somebody give me one hint? Thank you so much.

Comment: I' dont understand your notation if $f \in \Lambda^1(\mathbb{R}^m) $ how you can evualuate $f(v_1,...,v_m)$ ? where $(v_1,...,v_m)$ would be a matrix ? By the other side, note that If you have $f \in \Lambda^1(\mathbb{R}^m) $ and $\omega \in \Lambda^{m-1}(\mathbb{R}^m)$ then $f \wedge w \in \Lambda^m(\mathbb{R}^m)$ and $\dim \Lambda^m(\mathbb{R}^m)=1$.

Comment: @Pablo Herrera , we are not evaluating $f(v_1,...,v_m)$ but rather $(\omega\wedge f)(v_1,...,v_m)$ which makes sense.

Comment: What is $\operatorname{vol}(v_1,\dots,v_m)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give you a partial answer. Given a dual basis $v^1,...,v^m \in \Lambda^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{m})= \hom(\mathbb{R}^m,\mathbb{R})\cong \mathbb{R}^m$ of $v_1,...v_m$. The basis for $\Lambda^k(\mathbb{R}^m)$ is
$$\{v^{i_1}\wedge...\wedge v^{i_k}: 1\leq i_1<i_2...<i_k \leq n  \}.$$
Then, $\dim \Lambda^k(\mathbb{R}^m) = \binom{m}{k}$. In particular $\dim \Lambda^{m-1}(\mathbb{R}^{m}) = m = \dim \Lambda^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{m})$. Indeed we can construct the following homomorfism between $\Lambda^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{m})$ and $\Lambda^{m-1}(\mathbb{R}^{m})$ by
$$  v_i \to \wedge_{j\neq i} v^j,$$
where $j$ index are in increasing order.
So $\Lambda^{m-1}(\mathbb{R}^{m}) \cong \Lambda^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{m})\cong \mathbb{R}^m$.

For the other statement would help that $ \dim \Lambda^{m}(\mathbb{R}^{m})=1$ and $\det(v_1,...,v_m)$ can be a generator, so exists a unique constant $c \in \mathbb{R}$ where  $(\omega \wedge f) (v_1,...,v_m) = c\det(v_1,...,v_m)$.

Answer (score 2):

This is a result which I think is much clearer from an abstract perspective. Suppose $V$ is an $m$-dimensional real vector space along with a given volume form $\text{vol}\in \bigwedge^m(V)\setminus\{0\}$. Now, fix an $\omega\in \bigwedge^{m-1}(V)$ and define the following maps:

- $A_{\omega}: \bigwedge^1(V)=V^* \to \bigwedge^m(V)$ given by $f\mapsto \omega \wedge f$. i.e this is the "wedging map" (this is easily verified to be a linear map).
- Define $\Phi:\Bbb{R}\to \bigwedge^m(V)$ by $\Phi(c) = c \cdot \text{vol}$. This is clearly injective, and since both vector spaces are $1$-dimensional, this is also an isomorphism (all we're doing is mapping the basis element $1\in \Bbb{R}$ to the basis element $\text{vol}\in \bigwedge^m(V)$).
- Finally, let $\iota:V \to V^{**}$ be the canonical isomorphism, where for all $v\in V$ and all $f\in V^*$, $[\iota(v)](f):= f(v)$ (i.e it's the evaluation map).

Now, note that $\Phi^{-1} \circ A_{\omega}$ is a linear map $V^* \to \Bbb{R}$, in other words, $\Phi^{-1}\circ A_{\omega} \in V^{**}$ is an element of the second dual space, which is isomorphic to $V$. Now, define $v:= \iota^{-1}[\Phi^{-1}\circ A_{\omega}]\in V$.

This is the unique $v$ which you seek (for the initially given $\omega$), and I leave it as an exercise :) for you to unwind the definitions and prove that $\omega \wedge f = A_{\omega}(f) = f(v) \cdot \text{vol}$.

---

In this regard you may be interested to read up about the Hodge Dual operation which (on a $m$-dimensional, oriented, (pseudo-)inner product space) provides an isomorphism between $\bigwedge^{k}(V)$ and $\bigwedge^{m - k}(V)$. For example, pages 319-320 of Loomis and Sternberg's [Advanced Calculus](http://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Eshlomo/docs/Advanced_Calculus.pdf).